# Duplicate and overlapping text in TextView when using LiveData or StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin

To be as clear as possible, I'm going to show the problem with a gif.

[image: Text overlapping error]

As you can see, the text is overlapping in my emulator and I don't know how to solve it, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

It should be displayed correctly without overlapping. What I'm doing is subscribing to changes in both LiveData and StateFlow. When I press the button, I make it change the value, but instead of changing, it seems to return both values at once (Default and Hello). Could it be that the view is not refreshing? Or could it be a problem with my emulator?

Anyway, I'll leave all the code here in case you can figure it out.

FlowsFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.rr.stateflow_livedata_flow_sharedflow.databinding.FragmentFlowsBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest

class FlowsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_flows) {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFlowsBinding
    private val viewModel: FlowsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentFlowsBinding.bind(view)

        binding.btnLiveData.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.triggerLiveData()
        }

        binding.btnStateFlow.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.triggerStateFlow()
        }

        subscribeToObservables()
    }

    private fun subscribeToObservables() {
        viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            binding.tvLiveData.text = it
        }

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.stateFlow.collectLatest {
                binding.tvStateFlow.text = it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FlowsViewModel.kt

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

class FlowsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData("Default LiveData")
    val liveData: LiveData<String> = _liveData

    private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow("Default StateFlow")
    val stateFlow: StateFlow<String> = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun triggerLiveData() {
        _liveData.value = "Hello LiveData!"
    }

    fun triggerStateFlow() {
        _stateFlow.value = "Hello StateFlow!"
    }
}
```

fragment_flows.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FlowsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLiveData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLiveData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="LIVEDATA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLiveData" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStateFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLiveData" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStateFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="STATEFLOW"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvStateFlow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnStateFlow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="FLOW"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFlow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSharedFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFlow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSharedFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="SHAREDFLOW"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSharedFlow" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope that the text doesn't overlap and returns the latest value of LiveData and StateFlow.

Edit with more info: The application displays the view directly from the fragment, MainActivity only has a fragment container that I show below.

MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.add
import androidx.fragment.app.commit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            add<FlowsFragment>(R.id.mainActivityFragmentContainer)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivityFragmentContainer"
        android:name="com.rr.stateflow_livedata_flow_sharedflow.FlowsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_flows" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use Layout Inspector to find out what controls you actually have on your screen. I bet you have everything doubled.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This is not the solution, it's a bad way to solve the problem.

I just have to add this line of code in fragment_flows.xml.

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

Just by setting the background of the fragment to white, the text is no longer duplicated and overlapping.

Does anyone know why this happens? Why does what is drawn on the screen stick to the background if there is no background in the fragment layout?

Comment: It suggests that you're showing 2 fragments at once. White background obscures the other fragment. It isn't an actual solution, you've just swiped the problem under the rug. Find where the other instance comes from

Comment: @Agent_L I didn't realize I may have a duplicate fragment, but it makes sense. I'll see if I can find a way to display a fragment properly and learn how to use layout inspector.